# replace a string with sed from specific lines

Tags: sed

I do know how to replace a string from a specific line such as:

```
sed -i "<line number>s/<old string>/<new string>/g" <file name>
```

however I do not know how to replace a string from multiple lines for example from a line number 1 then 10 and then 100

Comment: sed doesn't support substitution by set of arbitrary numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an awk answer.

```
awk 'NR == 1 || NR == 10 || NR == 100 {gsub(/old/,"new")}; {print}' <file name>
```

### Explanation

- `NR == 1 || NR == 10 || NR == 100`: only do the following commands on one of these lines.
- `gsub(/old/,"new")`: substitute `/old/` with `new`.
- `{print}`: regardless of what line you are on, print the line.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you used `gsub(/old/,"new")` instead of `gsub("old","new")`?

Comment: @Culip Because that's what you are meant to use in awk. See `man awk`: "Lexical Conventions…An ERE constant shall begin with the <slash> character."

Comment: Got it, I thought the `<old string>` in the original question was a static string (not a regex pattern), so was your `old`.

Comment: @Culip It actually doesn't matter. `gsub` only takes an ERE, and doesn't work with static strings (see `man awk`: "gsub(ere, repl[, in])"). You can also test with `echo foo | awk '{gsub("f.o","bar")}; {print}'`, which still matches as an ERE. I think using `"` instead of `/` is still interpreted as an ERE, but is the "unconventional" syntax.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, sed addresses may only consist of a single line, or a *range* of lines.

However you could cobble something together using `sed -f -` to read commands from standard input, together with your shell. For example:

```
  printf '%ds/<old string>/<new string>/g\n' {1,10,100} | sed -f - file
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Alternative to avoid the pipe: `sed -f <(printf '%ds/line/LINE/g\n' {1,10,100}) file1`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative directly with sed:

```
 sed '1b1; 10b1; 100b1; b ;:1;s/<old string>/<new string>/g' <file name>
```

If the line number matches either 1, 10, or 100, branch to label 1; on other lines, just branch to the end (which, by default, prints the line).

somewhat automated:

```
 sed -e $(printf '%sb1;' 1 10 100) -e 'b; :1;s/<old>/<new>/g' <file name>
```

POSIXly (with default IFS):

```
 sed $(printf -- '-e %sb1 ' 1 10 100) -e 'b' -e':1' -e 's/<old>/<new>/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about:

```
sed -e '
     /something_identifying_startline/,/something_identifying_endline/{
        s/dog/cat/
        s/black/white/
        }
```

Comment: Welsome to U/L and thanks for posting an answer. However, this won't let you select multiple ranges (nor select by line number).