# sed display line number and add / remove comment

Tags: sed

I can display specify line number use the command

```
sed -n '22p; 24p; 27p' blah.conf
```

output

```
A
B
C
```

I need to insert comment # in this beginning of this 3 specify line number, I only successful run this command add comment from line 22 to 24 but not the specify line number, I have try many syntax but fail

```
sed -i '22,24 s/^/#/' blah.conf
```

output

```
#A
#B
#C
```

if insert comment work, I also need the the command to do the opposite remove the comment

output

```
A
B
C
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) your input file and ii) the output you want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (although you only show a file with 3 lines, so it doesn't help us test our solutions). So what is the problem? The command you show should work, does it fail? How does it fail? Do you just need the command to remove the comments?

Comment: @terdon As far as I can tell, Francis' problem is that Line 23 is commented while he only wants specific lines (22 and 24, not a range) to be commented/uncommented. I was in the middle of answering the question and then figured it's very likely a similar question would have already been asked. When I searched to check, I found one.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I don't think so. The example desired output has 3 commented lines, not two.

Comment: @terdon. That was the only possible problem I could get from the question but I agree that the question is unclear (the "possible duplicate" wording is appropriate). Francis, the question would be greatly improved, if you could edit the question to include lines in context, something like a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (no need for the example input to have more than 27 lines).

Comment: @terdon Yes, OP claims he can only to the replacement for a range of lines, but not for a list of specific line numbers. At least this is what I understand. So it's duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work toggling comments on specific lines keeping all blanks intact:

```bsh
$ cat file
A
# B
  C

$ sed -Ei '2b1;3b1;b;:1;s/^([[:blank:]]*)#/\1/;t;s/^([[:blank:]]*[^#[:blank:]])/#\1' file

# Run the same cat again
$ !cat
A
 B
#  C

# Run the same sed again
$ !sed

# Run the same cat again
$ !cat
A
# B
  C
```

Add `<n>b1;` for each line `<n>` that needs to be toggled.
Try first without `-i` or use `-i.bak`.

(`sed` branching [via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486863/236063))

Comment: Note that contatening commands with `;` after `b`, `t` or `:` is not allowed by POSIX and will not be portable. Better use separate lines or separate `-e` scripts.